# how to give padding to a label text in collectionviewcell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UICollectionViewCell` and inside cell their is one `label` without set width constraints that text automatically set ,but I need left and right spacing from the text in the label in swift

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

You should have custom `UILabel` class and in that class override `drawTextInRect` :

```
override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 10.0)
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))

}
```

If your label has more than one line it's better to use `UITextView` and change `textContainerInset` property:

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 10.0)
```